# Issue with geopackage syncing - geometries not populating in QGIS after sync (Qfield 2.2.1/QGIS 3.22.4)

Tags: geopackage, qfield, qfieldsync

I have a geopackage I have created and followed all steps I did last time I used QField--when packaged for offline editing, the geopackage from QGIS gets changed from "test" to "data". Data collection in the field works without issue, and I spatial information is collected from an RTK system linked by bluetooth. In the

When I sync, point data collected in "test" does not appear to sync, nor are there any attributes associated with it. Everything looks fine in Qfield, but nothing in QGIS.